If $\text{Hom}_R (M, R/I ) = {0}$ for all non-zero ideals, then $\text{Hom}_R (M, R ) = {0}$
This question comes from Rotman's Introduction to Homological Algebra (page 68, second edition).

2.22 Let $R$ be a domain and suppose that $M$ is an $R$-module with $\text{Hom}_R (M, R/I ) = \{0\}$ for all non-zero ideals $I$ in $R$. Prove that $\text{Hom}_R (M, R ) = \{0\}$.
Hint. Every $r \in \bigcap_{I \neq 0} I$ is nilpotent.

I have tried to prove this but I belive I have found a counter example.
Let our domain $R$ be $\mathbb{Q}$ and let $M$ be $\mathbb{Q}$ also, viewed as a module over itself. A field has only one non-zero ideal, itself. The quotient $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Q}=0$ so  $\text{Hom}_\mathbb{Q} (\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Q} )$ contains only the $0$ map. Hence $\text{Hom}_R (M, R/I ) = \{0\}$ for all non-zero ideals.
However,  $\text{Hom}_\mathbb{Q} (\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Q})\ne \{0\}$ as it also contains the identity (among other maps).
Have I misunderstood the question? It seems likely that a similar statement was intended, but I am not sure how to modify the hypotheses to make this true.

Not even the hint works. Maybe try to find a hypothesis for the hint to work. E.g. does it work if you restrict to proper non-zero ideals?

You are right, the statement is wrong (and the hint as well; and it is even misleading for non-fields).
We can just conclude that every homomorphism $M \to R$ factors through the intersection of all non-zero ideals of $R$ (see also the previous part of the exercise that you omitted). This is also the intersection of all non-zero principal ideals in $R$. That ideal consists of those elements that are divisible by any non-zero element.
Now, if $R$ is a domain that is not a field, then this intersection is zero. In fact, choose a non-zero non-unit $d$. If $r$ is non-zero and lies in the intersection of all non-zero principal ideals, then in particular $rd$ divides $r$, and then $d$ divides $1$, a contradiction.

The statement is correct if $R$ is a ring with $\bigcap_{I\neq 0} I = 0$. Then  $\text{Im}f \subseteq \bigcap_{I\neq 0} I = 0$ and therefore $f = 0$ for all $f \in \text{Hom}_R(M,R)$.
If $R$ is a domain then $\bigcap_{I\neq 0} I \neq 0$ if and only if $R$ is a field. So, the statement is correct if $R$ is a domain which is no field.
